# Maximum value, function of partition and its conjugate

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, integer-partitions, young-tableaux

Suppose that we have  $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ and  some $\alpha\ge 3$.

I am trying to find maximum value of:

$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|\lambda_{i}-\lambda_{j}^{*}|^{\alpha},$

over

$\{\lambda\in \mathbb{Z}^{n}: n\ge \lambda_{1}\ge \cdots\ge \lambda_{n} \ge 0 \},$

where

$\lambda_{j}^{*}=|\{i: \lambda_{i}\ge j\}|$  -  $\lambda^{*}$ is conjugate partition of $\lambda$.

I believe - due to some computer simulations - that argmax solution satisfies

a) $\lambda=\lambda^{*}$

b) $|\{j:\lambda_{j}\not=\lambda_{j+1}\}| \le 1$,

but I do not know how I could prove it. I will be glad for any ideas or insights.

Comment: This is maximum as a function of $n$?

Comment: Fixed to be what?

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding. Yes, maximum as function of $n$ - ofcourse.

Comment: Since you mentioned "conjugate partition", I assume you are familiar with Ferrers diagrams, and further I assume all $\lambda_i$ must be integers?  Interestingly, if you think of the Ferrers diagram being contained in an $n \times n$ square, each of your $|\lambda_i - \lambda^*_j|$ term can be written in one square.  I don't know that this visualization helps though...

Comment: Yes, I am looking for $\lambda_{i}$ integers. - I will edit the post. 
As a matter of fact I have been thinking of Ferrer diagrams (or Young tableaus) quite a lot. But my knowledge of this area is  shallow and I might have missed something important.